# replacing text in Powershell every alternate match

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40162913/replacing-a-block-of-text-in-powershell), and it's close to what I need to do, but the text I need to replace is inconsistent.

I need to replace `` "`r`n `` with `"`, but only the first of the 2 adjacent lines

example: (the full file is 50k lines and up to 500 chars wide)

```
    ID,Name,LinkedRecords
    54429,Abe,
    54247,Jonathan,"
    63460|63461"
    54249,Teresa,
    54418,Cody,
    58046,Joseph,
    58243,David,
    ,Barry,"
    74330"
    C8876,Simon,
    X_10934,David,
```

should become

```
    ID,Name,LinkedRecords
    54429,Abe,
    54247,Jonathan,"63460|63461"
    54249,Teresa,
    54418,Cody,
    58046,Joseph,
    58243,David,
    ,Barry,"74330"
    C8876,Simon,
    X_10934,David,
```

I can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089631/replacing-only-the-first-occurrence-of-a-word-in-a-string) will probably be useful, but I'm having a hard time getting the command to work as desired

Comment: [1] are the lines REALLY terminated with literal "backtick r backtick n" sequences? [2] how do you decide what lines to merge? it LOOKS like you want to mere any line that has no name with the line ahead of it.

Comment: I was using the formatting from the replacement strings - it is carriage return/linefeed

Comment: you may want to correct your posted sample data to NOT show the literal `cr/lf` chars. [*grin*] i see that `AdminOfThings` understood how to determine what lines to merge ... and posted a neat bit of code for it. i'm glad to know you got your solution ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `` `r`n `` characters are literal, then you can do the following:

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('c:\path\file.txt') -replace '(?<=,")`r`n\r?\n' |
    Set-Content c:\path\file.txt
```

If `` `r`n `` are actual carriage return and line feed chars, then you can do the following:

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('c:\path\file.txt') -replace '(?<=,")\r\n' | 
    Set-Content c:\path\file.txt
```

Note if memory becomes an issue, a different approach may be needed.