# Changing two lines of code with powershell in a .bat

Tags: python, powershell, batch-file, line-breaks

I've been following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40162913/replacing-a-block-of-text-in-powershell) and I've used this code in the .bat:

```
powershell -Command "(gc -Raw test.py) -replace 'test = ''lol''`r`nlol = ''test''', 'test1 = ''lol1''`r`nlol2 = ''test2''' | Out-File test2.py"
```

It does recognise backtick r backtick n because if replaces this file:
[image]

by this file:
[image]

My problem is that in the created file, I have backtick r backtick n instead of linebreaks. Is it normal? Am I missing something?

I also tried using `\r\n` instead of backticks r backticks n and the same happens (it's recognised but in the output file there is `\r\n` and not an actual linebreak (I'm on Windows 11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double-quotes for escape sequences, see [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.2).

An example for you to test:

```
$text = @'
test = 'lol'
lol = 'test'
'@

$text -replace "test = 'lol'\r?\nlol = 'test'", "test1 = 'lol1'`r`nlol2 = 'test2'"
```

As for your call to `powershell.exe` from the batch file, I believe this could work (you can use `"^""` for escaping):

```
powershell -Command "(gc -Raw test.py) -replace "^""test = 'lol'\r?\nlol = 'test'""", """test1 = 'lol1'`r`nlol2 = 'test2'"^"" | Out-File test2.py"
```

All credits on the call to `cmd` and the required escaping goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68136129/15339544).

Comment: But in my .bat file I already used double quotes for `-Command " ... "`. Should I use single quotes there and double quotes later (as in replacing `replace ' ... '` by `replace " ... "`) then?

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows try with my update

Comment: This happens:
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: My command was https://i.imgur.com/Bbjn9Sq.png

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows see my new update, that one worked for me. Hopefully this escaping non-sense from Cmd works. Will never understand why is Cmd needed to run powershell code but oh well..

Comment: it works, very obscure `"^""`, but i guess it does the job :D